# QR reader in Phantom doesn't deeplink to in-app browser

Tags: phantom, deeplink

I read [this](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/deeplinks-ios-and-android/other-methods/browse) and it says,

> Using their phone’s camera, users can scan a QR code to open a page
> directly within Phantom’s in-app browser. If a web app detects that a
> user is on mobile, it can also prompt the user to open a specific page
> within Phantom's in-app browser.

Does it mean I could use the QR scanner inside Phantom to scan a QR code containing their deeplink such as `https://phantom.app/ul/browse/<url>?ref=<ref>` and it will open the  inside the in-app browser? Or do I need to use a separate QR reader and scan the link and then it will open up the  in the dapp browser.

It seems like the latter works, but could I do the former too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the article you linked, we were referring to a QR-code reader (such as the iPhone camera app). The Phantom in-app QR code reader was originally built for sending SOL, but we will be upgrading it to handle deeplinks as well.